# Записать числа которые больше N в другой список

Tags: python

**Записать все числа в список А, и затем числа больше 5, записать в список С .**

Получается все, кроме добавления чисел которые больше 5 в список С.

```
A = []
C = []
b = int(input('Введите число...'))
c = int(input('Введите число...'))
d = int(input('Введите число...'))
e = int(input('Введите число...'))
f = int(input('Введите число...'))
A += b, c, d, e, f
for A in C:
    if b or c or d or e or f > 5:
        C +=

print(f'Список A: {A}' , f'Список С: {C}' )
```

Comment: судя по вашему коду, у вас _ничего_ не получается. что вы хотели сказать конструкцией `for A in C`?

Comment: @strawdog Да, Вы правы. Этой конструкцией я пытаюсь найти числа которые больше 5, но видимо не там пытаюсь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arrC = []
b = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))
c = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))
d = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))
e = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))
f = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))

plus5 =[]
minus5 =[]
for i in arrC:
    if i >5:
        plus5.append(i)
    else:
        minus5.append(i)

print('Числа больше 5:' + str(plus5)+'\n'+'Числа меньше 5: '+str(minus5))
```

Comment: Зачем здесь `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`? Им ничего не присваивается, они пустыми остаются. И если ввести 5, то покажет это число как *Числа меньше 5:*

Comment: Согласен лучше вместо стольких переменных использовать цикл

# b = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))
# c = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))
# d = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))
# e = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))
# f = arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))

for i in range(5):
    arrC.append(int(input('Введите число...')))

Answer (score 2):

В две строчки:

```python
a = [int(input('Введите число...')) for _ in range(5)]
print('Список A: {}, Список C: {}'.format(a, list(filter(lambda x: x>5, a))))
```

###### Вывод:

```
Введите число...23
Введите число...5
Введите число...4
Введите число...7
Введите число...245
Список A: [23, 5, 4, 7, 245], Список C: [23, 7, 245]
```

Переменные лучше не называть заглавными буквами, таким образом именуются классы. Смотри [pep8](https://all-python.ru/osnovy/pep-8.html):

> Классам дают имена в соответствии со стилем наименования CapitalizedWords.

Answer (score 1):

Изменил немного код, для удобства

```
arr = []
plus5 = []


for i in range(int(input('Сколько чисел хотите добавить? '))):
    number = int(input('Введите число...')) 
    arr.append(number)  
    if number > 5:
        plus5.append(number)
  

print(f'Список всех чисел: {arr}\nЧисла больше 5: {", ".join(map(str, plus5))}')
```

Comment: У Вас `print` по ширине уполз за экран. Можно избегая длинный `join` его разделить вот так: `print('Числа больше 5: ', end='')` `print(*plus5)` `print('Числа меньше 5: ', end='')` `print(*minus5)`. И попробуйте число 5 ввести, будет "*Числа меньше 5: 5*".

Comment: @DiMithras спасибо за совет, не стал разделять 'print', хотел уложиться в одну строчку,  на счет числа 5, я это изначально понимал, просто хотел ответить на конкретный вопрос "больше числа 5", но вы правы, если давать ответ то давать его полность)

Comment: да тут вроде про меньше 5 речи не шло, первый список по вопросу полным должен быть